# Overriding custom login error messages in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've been struggling with laravel 5.2 login function messages. I've override the default `sendFailedLoginResponse` function in AuthController which works for failed attempts.

But I need to override the `validate` function response as well which I could not figure out how to do that. Also I do not want to override the default login functionality in the AuthContrller and want to stick with the same `login` function.

The reason for overriding the `validate` function is that am making an angular app and want the response in json format with some custom keys.

Currently default `login` function in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticateUsers.php`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

I want the response something like in the below `sendFailedResponse` function in `AuthController`

```
 /**
 * Get failed request response
 *
 * @param null
 * @return null
 */
public function sendFailedLoginResponse()
{
    return response()->json( [ 'status' => false, 'message' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage() ]);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution by implementing `JWT` for authentication which I could think of is the best solution with Client side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Angular and handling json on laravel but I had similar problem while creating custom error message for postLogin function. take a look at this code, perhaps you could do something within form request.

This is my AuthController.php

```
use App\Http\Requests\LoginFormRequest;

/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(LoginFormRequest $request)
{
    return $this->login($request);
}
```

Try using form request on the function postLogin

```
class LoginFormRequest extends Request
{
  /**
   * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
   *
   * @return bool
   */
  public function authorize()
  {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules()
  {
    return [
        'email'            => 'required|email',
        'password'         => 'required|min:6',
    ];
  }

  public function messages()
  {
    return [
        'required'  => 'Your :attribute is required.',
        'min'  => ':attribute must be at least :min characters in length.',
        'email' => 'Please type valid email address.',
    ];
  }
}
```